# how are function's parameters are copied in case of reference parameter in C++?

Tags: c++11

As I understand, when we call a function, a memory block on stack part of memory of the program, gets allocated for the function call, and all the parameters are copied from the calling function into this memory block. But how does this work in case of pass by reference? is the address of the memory in the calling program is copied or is value copied? If nothing is getting copied then how is the function accessing the variable, when there is no value nor address in it's memory block on stack?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printIntRef(int &a) {
    printf("REF: a is %d, a address is %p\n", a, &a);
}

void printInt(int a) {
    printf("INT: a is %d, a address is %p\n", a, &a);
}

void printIntPointer(int *a) {
    printf("POINTER: *a is %d, a is %p, a address is %p\n", *a, a, &a);
}

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    printf("a is %d, a address is %p\n", a, &a);
    printIntRef(a);
    printInt(a);
    printIntPointer(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
a is 5, a address is 0x7fffea647024
REF: a is 5, a address is 0x7fffea647024
INT: a is 5, a address is 0x7fffea64700c
POINTER: *a is 5, a is 0x7fffea647024, a address is 0x7fffea647008
```

How could address of variable `a` in the function `printIntRef` be same as `a` in the `main` program? if a is a memory block on function's memory on stack

Comment: Usually it's implemented by passing a pointer (by value), so that your `printIntRef` and `printIntPointer` probably compile to the same code.  That's the whole point of a reference - the parameter `a` in `printIntRef` refers to the identical variable `a` in `main()`, and in particular they have the same address.

Comment: If you create a reference `int &r = a;` then `&r == &a`. This is how references work, by the definition of the language. Whether the reference variable itself is internally implemented as a pointer stored on the stack is an implementation detail, which you cannot rely on and should not be concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

when you pass a variable by pointer to a function you are passing the physical location in memory of the variable `a` that is in `main`. This means that in the function to which you pass the address a new variable `a` is not created, but only a pointer that contains the variable `a` of the `main`, which is why the memory addresses you print in `main` and `printIntRef` are the same. I recommend that you learn more about pointer management in C and not in C ++.

Comment: can you write the answer in english

Comment: Ops ahaha sorry